# Injection Rules for requirejs

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, requirejs

we're using requireJS to inject our dependencys where needed. Our structure is something like this:

```
        --> Controller
        --> Models
        --> Views
              |___Testview1.js
```

We've set some rules. Views are just allowed to inject controller, controller can inject models and views etc.

Is it possible to setup some rules to e.g. deny injecting a model into a view? If a view tries tzo inject a model, an exception should be thrown..

Answer (score 0):

No there is no build in way to do this. But you could write an wrapper to check this by yourself:

```
var defineOrig = define;

  function (name, deps, callback) {
    //make your checks
    if (passed) {
      defineOrig(name, deps, callback)
    } else {
      throw ('Error')
    }
  }
```